# How to correctly use keyboard hooks to press a key combination to block a key and to press it again to unblock it in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook

In the following code I get no build errors, but the message "The key A is blocked" is not printed at runtime:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x050

using namespace std;

string intToHexString(int intValue) {

    string hexStr;

    /// integer value to hex-string
    stringstream sstream;
    sstream << "0x" <<  hex << (int)intValue;

    hexStr = sstream.str();
    sstream.clear();    //clears out the stream-string

    return hexStr;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    BOOL locked = FALSE;
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct;
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            hookStruct = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
      /**
        * this is where the problem is
      */
            //ctrl+alt+n
            if (hookStruct->vkCode == 0x11 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x12 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x4E
                && !locked) {
                locked = TRUE;
                if (hookStruct->vkCode == 0x41) {
                    cout << "The key A is blocked" << endl;
                    return 1;
                }

            }
            else if (hookStruct->vkCode == 0x11 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x12 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x4E) {
                locked = FALSE;
                BlockInput(locked);
                cout << "The key is unblocked" << endl;

            }
            else {
                return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    char key_pressed;
    int ascii_value;
    string key_press_special;
    HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    cout << "press any key to see it's Character, ASCII and Scan Code" << endl;
    cout << "Press ESC key to Exit" << endl;
    while(1) {
        key_pressed = _getch();
        if (key_pressed == 13) {
            key_press_special = "Enter";
            cout << "Character: " << key_press_special << endl;
        }
        else if (key_pressed == 9) {
            key_press_special = "Tab";
            cout << "Character: " << key_press_special << endl;
        }
        else if (key_pressed == 27) {
            key_press_special = "ESC";
            cout << "Character: " << key_press_special << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Character: " << key_pressed << endl;
        }
         ascii_value = key_pressed;
        cout << "The ASCII Value is: " << ascii_value << endl;
        int scan = MapVirtualKey(ascii_value, 0);
        string scanCode = intToHexString(scan);
        cout << "Scan Code is: " << scanCode << endl;

        if (key_pressed == 27) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***I ran the code and there are no bugs or errors but when i try out the combination, it does not do what it's suppose to do*** Isn't that the definition of a bug?

Comment: ***hookStruct->vkCode == 0x11 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x12 && hookStruct->vkCode == 0x4E*** This can never be true.

Comment: sorry didn't know that was the definition

Comment: why is tha? @drescherjm. because here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, that's the virtual key Code.

Comment: The last time I did this was ~20 years ago. I think you need to use a mask,  I mean (hookStruct->vkCode & VK_SOMETHING == VK_SOMETHING) for each conditional.

Comment: ***why is tha?*** Because a number can't be 0x11 and 0x12 at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Your hook is trying to process the complete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>N</kbd> sequence as a single virtual key, and that is simply not how it works.  You have to process the keys individually.

Try something more like this instead:

```
bool ctrlDown = false;
bool altDown = false;
bool nDown = false;
bool locked = false;

void UpdateLock()
{
    if (ctrlDown && altDown && nDown) {
        locked = !locked;
        if (!locked) BlockInput(FALSE);
        cout << (locked ? "" : "not ") << "locked" << endl;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) lParam;
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            switch (hookStruct->vkCode)
            {
            case VK_CONTROL:
                if (!ctrlDown) {
                    ctrlDown = true;
                    UpdateLock();
                }
                break;
            case VK_MENU:
                if (!altDown) {
                    altDown = true;
                    UpdateLock();
                }
                break;
            case 'N':
                if (!nDown) {
                    nDown = true;
                    UpdateLock();
                }
                break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            switch (hookStruct->vkCode)
            {
            case VK_CONTROL:
                ctrlDown = false;
                break;
            case VK_MENU:
                altDown = false;
                break;
            case 'N':
                nDown = false;
                break;
           }
           break;
        }

        if ((hookStruct->vkCode == 'A') && locked) {
            cout << "The key A is blocked" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: .I implemented your method but still isn't blocking the A key or showing anything from the LowLevelKeyboardProc at all.

Comment: Did you verify that `SetWindowsHookEx()` is not failing? You are calling it with `dwThreadId=0` to install the hook globally, which requires the hook code to be in a DLL so it can be injected into other processes, but you are setting `hMod=0` since the code is not in a DLL. If you just want to hook the calling thread, set `dwThreadId` to the return value of `GetCurrentThreadId()`

Comment: LowLevelKeyboardProc will never receive VK_CONTROL. it's always VK_LCONTROL or VK_RCONTROL

Answer (score 0):

The upvoted answer won't work because LowLevelKeyboardProc will never receive VK_CONTROL, at least in WinXP and later. it's always VK_LCONTROL or VK_RCONTROL.  Otherwise it's a good idea, but obviously it's never been compiled and tested so it probably has other bugs as well.

For an example that is perhaps overkill but lovingly commented, check out the source to autohotkey:

https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/master/Source/hook.cpp#L201